# How to avoid nested font sizes with CKEditor?

Tags: ckeditor

If I randomly select text within the same P element and set font sizes with the font plugin, the markup is soon littered with nested SPAN elements that holds the font-sizes.

Instead I would like the font-size to be set on the P element and never be nested, much like the style block plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed in CKEditor **4.4.6** released on November 25, 2014. This change was introduced in [ticket #12630](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/12403).

Comment: What a coincidence! Didn't see that ticket while Googling around. =)

Comment: Yeah, I smiled when I saw your question, too :) CKEditor 4.4.6 was released yesterday, so I updated the answer for future reference.

Comment: Still, even with the new version it nests span elements instead of setting the font-size on the block element.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want to accomplish, then. Font size is an "inline" feature, it works on selections and does not apply to entire blocks -- this behavior is expected by the users (it's the same as e.g. in Google Docs or MS Word). If you want to apply a feature at block level, you would need to implement it as a [text format](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_format) or a [block style](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_styles-section-style-types).